# FATAL EXCEPTION: main after NetworkOnMainThread Exception

Tags: android

I have an app which connect to a .NET service for id after providing a phone number and a password. The ID is created on the server side.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Settings.getSettings(this);

    sqlHelper = SqlHelper.getSqlHelper(this);

    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(SplashScreen.this, "Connecting to server.. ", "Please wait for a few seconds...", true);

    Thread splashThread = new Thread()  
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try 
            {
                if (SqlHelper.checkDataBase(SplashScreen.this) == true)
                {
                    uploadData();

                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Log.e("Error! ", " Data could not be uploaded at the moment");
            } 
            finally 
            {
                runOnUiThread(changeMessage);
                finish();
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClassName("show.android.fife", "show.android.fife.Monitor");
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.infromright, R.anim.outtoleft);
                dialog.dismiss();
                SplashScreen.this.finish();
            }
        }
    };
    splashThread.start();
}
```

uploadData() Method is as follows:

```
public void uploadData()
{
    int userId = this.getUserId();
    if(userId != 0 || userId != -1)//user setup
    {
        String wsResponse = "";
        try
        {
            wsResponse = WebServiceUtils.callWebService(encryptData(
                            this.getUnsubmittedQuestionnaires(this.csrUnsubmittedQuestionnaires())), 
                                Integer.toString(userId), "insertAnswers", this);

            wsResponse = WebServiceUtils.callWebService(
                    encryptData(this.getUnsubmittedPEF(crsUnsubmittedPEF())), 
                    Integer.toString(userId), "insertPEF", this);

            if(wsResponse=="Thanks, data has been submitted")
            {
                this.updateDbSetAllSent();
            }
            currentStatus = COMPLETE;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            currentStatus = FAILED;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following errors. I know there are a few similar questions, but could not resolve my error.

---

LogCat below:

```
02-06 15:00:31.281: W/Settings(6522): Setting http_proxy has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, value is unchanged.
02-06 15:00:45.226: W/System.err(6522): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-06 15:00:45.226: W/System.err(6522):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
02-06 15:00:45.226: W/System.err(6522):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
02-06 15:00:45.226: W/System.err(6522):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
02-06 15:00:45.231: W/System.err(6522):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
02-06 15:00:45.231: W/System.err(6522):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
02-06 15:00:45.231: W/System.err(6522):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
02-06 15:00:45.236: W/System.err(6522):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
02-06 15:00:45.236: W/System.err(6522):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
02-06 15:00:45.241: W/System.err(6522):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
02-06 15:00:45.241: W/System.err(6522):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
02-06 15:00:45.241: W/System.err(6522):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:460)
02-06 15:00:45.246: W/System.err(6522):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:432)
02-06 15:00:45.246: W/System.err(6522):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
02-06 15:00:45.251: W/System.err(6522):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
02-06 15:00:45.251: W/System.err(6522):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
02-06 15:00:45.251: W/System.err(6522):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:188)
02-06 15:00:45.256: W/System.err(6522):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:280)
02-06 15:00:45.256: W/System.err(6522):     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.openOutputStream(ServiceConnectionSE.java:109)
02-06 15:00:45.256: W/System.err(6522):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:157)
02-06 15:00:45.261: W/System.err(6522):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:96)
02-06 15:00:45.261: W/System.err(6522):     at show.android.fife.WebServiceUtils.callGetIdWebService(WebServiceUtils.java:88)
02-06 15:00:45.266: W/System.err(6522):     at show.android.fife.WebServiceSetupActivity.getId(WebServiceSetupActivity.java:73)
02-06 15:00:45.266: W/System.err(6522):     at show.android.fife.WebServiceSetupActivity.access$0(WebServiceSetupActivity.java:71)
02-06 15:00:45.271: W/System.err(6522):     at show.android.fife.WebServiceSetupActivity$1.onClick(WebServiceSetupActivity.java:66)
02-06 15:00:45.276: W/System.err(6522):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3627)
02-06 15:00:45.276: W/System.err(6522):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14329)
02-06 15:00:45.276: W/System.err(6522):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-06 15:00:45.281: W/System.err(6522):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-06 15:00:45.281: W/System.err(6522):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 15:00:45.286: W/System.err(6522):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
02-06 15:00:45.286: W/System.err(6522):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 15:00:45.291: W/System.err(6522):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 15:00:45.291: W/System.err(6522):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
02-06 15:00:45.291: W/System.err(6522):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
02-06 15:00:45.296: W/System.err(6522):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 15:00:45.296: D/AndroidRuntime(6522): Shutting down VM
02-06 15:00:45.296: W/dalvikvm(6522):       threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c651f8)
02-06 15:00:45.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6522): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 15:00:45.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6522): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 15:00:45.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6522):     at show.android.fife.WebServiceSetupActivity.getId(WebServiceSetupActivity.java:73)
02-06 15:00:45.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6522):     at show.android.fife.WebServiceSetupActivity.access$0(WebServiceSetupActivity.java:71)
02-06 15:00:45.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6522):     at show.android.fife.WebServiceSetupActivity$1.onClick(WebServiceSetupActivity.java:66)
02-06 15:00:45.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6522):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3627)
02-06 15:00:45.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6522):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14329)
02-06 15:00:45.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6522):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-06 15:00:45.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6522):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-06 15:00:45.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6522):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 15:00:45.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6522):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
02-06 15:00:45.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6522):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 15:00:45.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6522):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 15:00:45.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6522):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
02-06 15:00:45.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6522):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
02-06 15:00:45.311: E/AndroidRuntime(6522):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: plz post uploadData() method code also are u accessing or updating Ui in uploadData() method ?

Comment: Obvious error, please use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged. See the document Designing for Responsiveness.

See [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in all off your network connections to solve this problem.

Comment: Yeah but always that I had this problem, it worked for me..  @LiaqatG post the method `uploadData()` as @ρяσѕρєяK said

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. Was trying to get my head round Async...work in progress. As for the uploadData() method, please see the update question above.

Comment: Thanks to all for the replies. Please can someone direct me to a **Working Example** of AsyncTask. All the samples/example I have come across so far are erroneous and adds to the confusion and frustration. Thanks Liaqat.

Answer (score 1):

starting from **honeycomb** android does not permit network operations on the main thread, hence you are getting the exception. move all network related operations to a separate thread. There are several options like AsyncTask (this is suitable for short background tasks), Executor, Handler etc., tutorials for which are easily available on the net. Try to implement yourself, if you face any errors again, then post here. Good luck!